# SwiftUI: Overlap between views in VStack

Tags: html, webview, swiftui, webkit, uiviewrepresentable

I learned to create this `HTMLStringView` to show html strings in my app:

```
struct HTMLStringView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let htmlContent: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

I found that there is a `height: 112` overlap between the `ZStack` and whatever view below it. As `zIndex = 1`, if I want to show the `HTMLStringView` below the `ZStack`, I will have to put a `Rectangle` of height 112 in between. As shown in the code below:

```
ScrollView{

                            VStack(spacing:0){


                                ZStack{

                                    ZStack (alignment: .leading){
                                        UrlImageView(urlString: thisItem.cover_img, imageWidth: self.expandedScreen_shown ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width : self.cardWidth, imageHeight: self.maxCardHeight)
                                    }.offset(y: self.expandedScreen_shown ? 0 : 0)
                                        .clipped()
                                        .background(Color.white)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

                                    VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                        Spacer()

                                        Text("\(thisItem.title)")
                                            .font(.title)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                            .padding(.leading, 23)
                                            .padding(.trailing, 23)
                                            .padding(.top, 20)
                                            .padding(.bottom, 10)

                                        Text("\(thisItem.author) | \(thisItem.source)")
                                            .font(.body)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                            .padding(.leading, 23)
                                            .padding(.trailing, 23)
                                            .padding(.bottom, 20)
                                    }

                                }.frame(height: self.maxCardHeight * 0.5)
                                    .zIndex(1)

                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.white)
                                    .frame(height: 112)

                                HTMLStringView(htmlContent: "<p>Hello World!</p>")
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color.white)
                                    .frame(height: 300)
                                    .border(Color.green)

                            }
```

I am currently using iPhone 11 as my emulator, and the overlap height changes when I switch to emulators with other screen sizes. Does anyone know why there is an overlap? If I cannot get rid of it, what proportion is it with respect to the screen size?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have the following test code that shows there is no problem with
 expanding the view that is set to be invisible initially.

So my answer is, no it is not a problem with your expanding view that is set to be invisible initially.
 The problem must be related to something else in your code.

I would look closely at the

```
 ZStack{...}
 .frame(height: self.maxHeight)
 .zIndex(1)
```

especially the "self.maxHeight" and the height of the Rectangle.

As a test replace "self.maxHeight" with say 50, and see what happens.

Another edit.

```
class Item {
var title = "title"
var author = "author"
var source = "source"
var cover_img = "cover_img"
}

struct ContentView: View {

@State var expandedScreen_shown = false
@State var maxHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2
@State var cardWidth = CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
@State var maxCardHeight = CGFloat(444)

func itemView(_ thisItem: Item) -> some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
        Text(thisItem.title)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding(.leading, 23)
            .padding(.trailing, 23)
            .padding(.top, 20)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)

        Text("\(thisItem.author) | \(thisItem.source)")
            .font(.body)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding(.leading, 23)
            .padding(.trailing, 23)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}

func imageView(_ thisItem: Item) -> some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            ZStack (alignment: .leading) {
                UrlImageView(urlString: thisItem.cover_img, imageWidth: self.expandedScreen_shown ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width : self.cardWidth, imageHeight: self.maxCardHeight)
            }.frame(width: self.expandedScreen_shown ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width : self.cardWidth, height: self.maxCardHeight)
                .offset(y: self.expandedScreen_shown ? 0 : 0)
                .clipped()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

            self.itemView(thisItem)

        }.frame(height: self.maxCardHeight * 0.5)
            .zIndex(1)
    }
}

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack (spacing:0) {

            imageView(Item())

            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 112)

            HTMLStringView(htmlContent: "<p>Hello World!</p>")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .frame(height: 300)
                .border(Color.green)
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hi, it does not seem to solve the problem when I change it to 50. Just to provide some more info here: `@State var maxHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2`. I should have named it more clearly. Do you know what else might be wrong here? Or do you need some more information or code for reference?

Comment: I think the basic problem is that you cannot fit all the views into the space.
ZStack=half the screen, HTMLStringView=infinity and Rectangle=the full screen. 

So the HTMLStringView is squeezed to nothing between the ZStack and the Rectangle.

Adjust the heights, maybe use GeometryReader to assign relative sizes to the views.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how the space is used.

Comment: Actually, the whole VStack is within a ScrollView. And I found a very weird thing that, there is always `heigh: 112` overlap between the ZStack and whatever view below it in the ScrollView. As `zIndex = 1`, a HTMLStringView of a height smaller than 112 will always be hidden behind it. I have edited my original code so that you can see the situation. But my question now is that: what has caused the `heigh: 112` overlap? I assume this might be somewhat proportional to the screen size (my emulator is iPhone 11). So how can I get rid of it for other screen sizes?

Comment: I've edited the answer again to show a possible approach.